# Объясните, пожалуйста, как правильно понять строку parameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Можно ли заменить ReturnValue на что либо другое и что еще можно заменить? И в каких случаях это применять?

```
static int InsertCustomer()
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IdentityProcedure", connection) { CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure };
            SqlParameter parameter = cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter());
            parameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue; // после выполнения комманды parameter будет содержать возвращаемое значение хранимой процедуры 

            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("New customer with CustomerNo {0} was added", parameter.Value);
            return (int)parameter.Value;
        }
```

Comment: Можно ли заменить ReturnValue на что либо другое и что еще можно заменить? И в каких случаях это применять?

Comment: Не задавайте вопросы в комментариях. Отредактируйте сообщение, перенеся в него вопрос из коммента.

Answer (score 1):

Вы работаете с ООП, что означает работу с классами и методами, которые они содержат. В Visual Studio вы можете зажать Ctrl и по левому клику попасть в необходимый класс или перейти к методу, где он определен.

```
 parameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

Нажмите данным способом на "ParameterDirection". Все методы, которые доступны в этом классе доступны к использованию в других классах(точнее помеченные модификатором public).

Как используются методы и что они делают обычно пишут в документации, но в большинстве библиотек над методом есть комментарий.

Comment: Я полагаю, у автора скорее вопрос о том, как работают sql-запросы, как можно вернуть/получить значения из них.